# How to add custom date vector into plot?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a date vector called `prod.dat.ordered.distinct1` which looks like this:

```
prod.dat.ordered.distinct1 <- c("2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", 
"2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", 
"2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12"
)
```

Now in my plot I receive on the y-axis the numbers 1 to 18 instead of my  `prod.dat.ordered.distinct1` vector... 
What changes do I have to make in order to get my date values on the y-axis? Here is my code:

```
mydatal <- testdatensatz[testdatensatzSbaureihe == "F10",] 
prod.dat1 <- as.Date(mydata1$produktionsdatumf2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
prod.dat1 <- format(prod.dat1, format = "%Y-%m") 
befund1 <- mydata1$befundnummer 
prod.dat.befund1 <- data.frame(p = prod.dat1, b = befund1) 

prod.dat.befund.ordered1 <- prod.dat.befund1[order(prod.dat.befund1$p), ]

prod.dat.ordered.distinct1 <- prod.dat.befund.ordered1$p[!duplicated(prod.dat.befund.ordered1$p)]

t1 <- as.data.frame(table(prod.dat.befund1))
matt = matrix(nrow = length(prod.dat.ordered.distinctl), ncol = 2) 
Produktionsdatum <- c() 
relativeHaufigkeit <- c() 
for (i in 1:length(prod.dat.ordered.distinct1)) 
{ 
  tl.date <- tl[t1$p == prod.dat.ordered.distinct1[i], ] 
  number.ref1 <- tl.date[tl.date$b == 0, 3] 
  number.faults1 <- sum(t1.date[as.numeric(t1.date$b) > 1, 3]) 
  Produktionsdatum[i] <- prod.dat.ordered.distinctl[i]
  relativeHaufigkeit[i]<- round((number.faults1 / number.refl)  * 100, digits = 0) 
}

df1 <- data.frame(Produktionsdatum, relativeHaufigkeit) 
df1$gr <- df1$Produktionsdatum %in% r 
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Produktionsdatum,y=relativeHaufigkeit, color=gr)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=r1, alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Dear rayray, welcome to SO! Could you post not images of code but text of code itself. It is rather tedious for people who will try to help you to retype the data to check your code. The probability of answer is greately reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther problem in the line with

`Produktionsdatum[i] <- prod.dat.ordered.distinct1[i]`

It converts factors into integer. If you wrap it into `as.character` function, then dates will be indicated at the x-axis. Moreover if you would like to use `geom_vline` you need to use separate aesthetics.

Please see the code below:

```
prod.dat.ordered.distinct1 <- c("2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", 
                                "2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", 
                                "2013-07", "2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12"
)

testdatensatz <- data.frame(baureihe = "F10",
                          produktionsdatumf2 = c("2012-08-02", "2012-08-03", "2012-09-01", "2012-10-05"),
                          befundnummer = c(1, 0, 2, 1))

relativeHaufigkeit <- c(1, 2, 3, 1)
t1 <- data.frame(p = factor("2012-07", "2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10"), b = 0)



mydata1 <- testdatensatz[testdatensatz$baureihe == "F10",] 

prod.dat1 <- as.Date(mydata1$produktionsdatumf2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
prod.dat1 <- format(prod.dat1, format = "%Y-%m") 
befund1 <- mydata1$befundnummer 
prod.dat.befund1 <- data.frame(p = prod.dat1, b = befund1) 

prod.dat.befund.ordered1 <- prod.dat.befund1[order(prod.dat.befund1$p), ]

prod.dat.ordered.distinct1 <- prod.dat.befund.ordered1$p[!duplicated(prod.dat.befund.ordered1$p)]

t1 <- as.data.frame(table(prod.dat.befund1))
matt = matrix(nrow = length(prod.dat.ordered.distinct1), ncol = 2) 
Produktionsdatum <- c() 
relativeHaufigkeit <- c() 

for (i in 1:length(prod.dat.ordered.distinct1)) { 
  t1.date <- t1[t1$p == prod.dat.ordered.distinct1[i], , drop = FALSE] 
  # number.ref1 <- t1.date[t1.date$b == 0, 3] 
  number.ref1 <- t1.date[t1.date$b == 0, 3] 
  number.faults1 <- sum(t1.date[as.numeric(t1.date$b) > 1, 3]) 
  Produktionsdatum[i] <- as.character(prod.dat.ordered.distinct1[i]) #
  relativeHaufigkeit[i]<- round((number.faults1 / number.ref1)  * 100, digits = 0) 
}


df1 <- data.frame(Produktionsdatum, relativeHaufigkeit, gr = sample(1:2, length(Produktionsdatum), replace = TRUE)) 

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Produktionsdatum, y = relativeHaufigkeit, color = gr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1, alpha=0.5)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image: plotted]